# Group points which on several straight lines

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, computational-geometry

I have some points, they are distributed on three straight lines, how to group points on the same line? I have tried `FindCurvePath`, but I got the wrong result. I also thought about `GatherBy` or `Split`, but I don't know how to write the second parameter.

```
pts = RandomSample@
   Join[RandomPoint[Line[{{0.3, 0.4}, {0.9, 1.4}}], 10], 
    RandomPoint[Line[{{0.2, 0.3}, {2.2, 0.3}}], 10], 
    RandomPoint[Line[{{2, 0.5}, {1.4, 1.6}}], 10]];

curve = FindCurvePath[pts]
Show[Graphics[{Point@pts}], ListLinePlot[pts[[#]] & /@ curve]]
```

[image]

Comment: You may find [`CollinearPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CollinearPoints.html) and [`ResourceFunction["FindExtraordinaryLines"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FindExtraordinaryLines/) useful.

Comment: In your example, the lines intersect at points that are not inside the convex hull of the points. Is that a general rule for your needs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

```
curve = FindCurvePath[pts];

ip = Join @@ 
      (Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length @ pts, {3}, Range[2, Length @ pts]]); 

partition = Quiet @ First @
   MinimalBy[ip, Total[LinearModelFit[#, x, x]["BIC"] & /@ 
       TakeList[pts[[Most@curve[[1]]]], #]] &]
```

> ```
> {10, 10, 10}
> ```

```
bf = LinearModelFit[#, x, x]["BestFit"] & /@ TakeList[pts[[Most@curve[[1]]]], partition]
```

> ```
> {0.3 + 5.43214*10^-17 x, 4.16667 - 1.83333 x, -0.1 + 1.66667 x}
> ```

```
Show[Plot[bf, {x, 0, 3}], 
 ListPlot[TakeList[pts[[Most@curve[[1]]]], partition]]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
chmboundary = RegionBoundary @ ConvexHullMesh @ pts
```

[image]

```
grouped = GroupBy[Sort @ MeshPrimitives[chmboundary, 1], 
   Round[#, 10^-3] &@*Ratios@*First@*Apply[Differences] -> SortBy[#[[1, 1]] &], 
    {RegionMeasure @ RegionUnion @ #, 
     InfiniteLine @ {#[[1, 1, 1]], #[[-1, -1, -1]]}} &];

infinitelines = Last /@ MaximalBy[Values[grouped], First, 3]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{MapThread[{AbsoluteThickness[7], #, #2} &, 
       {{Red, Green, Blue}, infinitelines}], 
   AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1], Gray, Last /@ Values[grouped],
   Black, PointSize[Small], Point @ pts}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

One way is to randomly sample the points and check for approximate collinearity (note: I found the function `CollinearPoints` to be too precise for this task). When this condition is met, fit an `InfiniteLine` to these collinear points and remove points in the set that are on the line (or extremely close). Proceed in this way until all points are removed.

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomSample@
   Join[RandomPoint[Line[{{0.3, 0.4}, {0.9, 1.4}}], 10], 
    RandomPoint[Line[{{0.2, 0.3}, {2.2, 0.3}}], 10], 
    RandomPoint[Line[{{2, 0.5}, {1.4, 1.6}}], 10]];
approxcollinear[pts_] := With[{reg = Line[pts[[{1, -1}]]]},
   With[{rdf = RegionDistance[reg]},
    Return@AllTrue[pts, rdf[#] < 0.0001 &]
    ]
   ];
online[pts_, line_] := With[{rdf = RegionDistance[line]},
  Select[pts, rdf[#] < 0.0001 &]
  ]
findcolin[pts_, n_] := Module[{rs = RandomSample[pts, n]},
  While[Not@approxcollinear@rs,
   rs = RandomSample[pts, n];
   ]; Return[rs]]
newpts = pts;
lines = Reap[While[newpts != {},
     rs = findcolin[newpts, 4];
     infl = InfiniteLine[rs[[{1, -1}]]];
     Sow[infl];
     ontheline = online[newpts, infl];
     newpts = Complement[newpts, ontheline];
     ListPlot[newpts]
     ]][[2, 1]];
Graphics[{lines, Red, Point@pts}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

They can then be gathered up by checking region distance:

```
gathered = Reap[Do[
     Sow[Select[pts, RegionDistance[line, #] < 0.001 &]],
     {line, lines}]][[2, 1]];
ListPlot[gathered, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146105/10397) a general solution could be this

```
func[parms_List][x_] :=parms.Table[x^(n-1),{n,Length[parms]}]
dist[f_][{x_, y_}] := Abs[(y - f[x])]^2

sol2 = Last@With[{n = 2, m =3},
   NMinimize[
    Total@Map[Function[{L}, Min @@ Table[
         dist[func[Array[c[#, k] &, n]]][L]
         , {k, m}]], pts]
    , Flatten[Table[c[i, j], {i, n}, {j, m}]]
,Method->"DifferentialEvolution"]]
```

Here `n=2` so we search for straight lines, i.e polynomial of degree $n-1=1$, and `m=3` the number of curves, in this case, three lines. `func` define the shape of the curve you want to fit, and `dist` define a distance function to minimize.

The main concept is that you want to minimize ([`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)) the minimum ([`Min`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html)) distance (`dist`) from each point to any of the alternative curves *i.e.* you minimize the distance to the closest curve, in this case, the closest line.

With some data

```
SeedRandom[42];
pts = RandomSample@
   Join[RandomPoint[Line[{{0.3, 0.4}, {0.9, 1.4}}], 10], 
    RandomPoint[Line[{{0.2, 0.3}, {2.2, 0.3}}], 10], 
    RandomPoint[Line[{{2, 0.5}, {1.4, 1.6}}], 10]];
```

Plotting the results

```
SetOptions[ListPlot
,PlotRange->All
,PlotTheme->"Scientific"];
Show[
 ListPlot@GatherBy[
   pts
   , Position[#, Min[#]] &[
     Table[dist[func[{c[1, k], c[2, k]} /. sol2]][#], {k, 3}]] &
   ],
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   Table[
     func[{c[1, k], c[2, k]}][x]
     , {k, 4}] /. sol2
   ]
  , {x, 0, 10}
  ]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We may determine the first line by taking an arbitrary point: p0, e.g. the first one, and determine its nearest neighbor: pn. This determines a line. Now, we calculate a perpendicular unit vector: perp. The scalar product of perp with any of the remaining point gives the distance to the line. If we select all points that have a small distance to the line we have all the points on the line. Next, we eliminate these points and repeat the process with the remaining points.

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomSample@
   Join[RandomPoint[Line[{{0.3, 0.4}, {0.9, 1.4}}], 10], 
    RandomPoint[Line[{{0.2, 0.3}, {2.2, 0.3}}], 10], 
    RandomPoint[Line[{{2, 0.5}, {1.4, 1.6}}], 10]];
getLines[pts0_] := Module[{pts, l1, l2, l3},
   getlin[ps_] := Module[{p0, pn, perp, lin},
     p0 = ps[[1]];
     pn = Nearest[Rest@ps, p0][[1]];
     perp = Normalize[{{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . (pn - p0)];
     {lin = Select[ps, Abs[perp . (# - p0)] < 0.01 &],
      Complement[ps, lin]}];
   {l1, pts} = getlin[pts0];
   {l2, pts} = getlin[pts];
   {l3, pts} = getlin[pts];
   {l1, l2, l3}
   ];
ListLinePlot[getLines[pts], Epilog -> Point[pts]]
```

[image]